# How to retrieve and log authenticated user in a React.JS / Next.JS application using winston logger?

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, winston, express-winston

I am using winston logger in my React.JS / Next.JS. I would like to retrieve and log authenticated user in an `dynamicMeta` function?

https://github.com/bithavoc/express-winston#dynamic-meta-data-from-request-or-response